# Editar varibale de array de session

Tags: php

Tengo una sesion con los productos de una compra y quiero que el precio sea editable.
Ya cree un DataTable con un campo editable y comprobe que la variable llegue hasta el servidor.

Pero al actualizar la pagina no se reflejan los cambios.

````
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    session_start();
    include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/gestion/models/claseProducto.php');
    include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/gestion/models/claseCliente.php');

    class Carritoa
    {
        //aquí guardamos el contenido del carrito
        private $carrito = array();
        //seteamos el carrito exista o no exista en el constructor
        public function __construct()
        {
            if(!isset($_SESSION["carritoa"]))
            {
                $_SESSION["carritoa"] = null;
                $this->carrito["precio_total"] = 0;
                $this->carrito["articulos_total"] = 0;
            }
            $this->carrito = $_SESSION['carritoa'];
        }
        //añadimos un producto al carrito
        public function add($articulo = array())
        {
            //primero comprobamos el articulo a añadir, si está vacío o no es un 
            //array lanzamos una excepción y cortamos la ejecución
            if(!is_array($articulo) || empty($articulo))
            {
                throw new Exception("Error, el articulo no es un array!", 1);
            }
            //nuestro carro necesita siempre un id producto, cantidad y precio articulo
            if(!$articulo["id"] || !$articulo["cantidad"] || !$articulo["precio"])
            {
                throw new Exception("Error, el articulo debe tener un id, cantidad y precio!", 1);
            }
            //nuestro carro necesita siempre un id producto, cantidad y precio articulo
            if(!is_numeric($articulo["id"]) || !is_numeric($articulo["cantidad"]) || !is_numeric($articulo["precio"]))
            {
                throw new Exception("Error, el id, cantidad y precio deben ser números!", 1);
            }
            //debemos crear un identificador único para cada producto
            $unique_id = md5($articulo["id"]);
            //creamos la id única para el producto
            $articulo["unique_id"] = $unique_id;
            //si no está vacío el carrito lo recorremos 
           if(!empty($this->carrito))
            {
                foreach ($this->carrito as $row)
                {
                    //comprobamos si este producto ya estaba en el 
                    //carrito para actualizar el producto o insertar
                    //un nuevo producto 
                    if($row["unique_id"] === $unique_id)
                    {
                        //si ya estaba sumamos la cantidad
                        $articulo["cantidad"] = $row["cantidad"] + $articulo["cantidad"];
                    }
                }
            }
            //evitamos que nos pongan números negativos y que sólo sean números para cantidad y precio
            $articulo["cantidad"] = trim(preg_replace('/([^0-9\.])/i', '', $articulo["cantidad"]));
            $articulo["precio"] = trim(preg_replace('/([^0-9\.])/i', '', $articulo["precio"]));
            //añadimos un elemento total al array carrito para 
            //saber el precio total de la suma de este artículo
            $articulo["total"] = $articulo["cantidad"] * $articulo["precio"];
            //primero debemos eliminar el producto si es que estaba en el carrito
            $this->unset_producto($unique_id);
            ///ahora añadimos el producto al carrito
            $_SESSION["carritoa"][$unique_id] = $articulo;
            //actualizamos el carrito
            $this->update_carrito();
            //actualizamos el precio total y el número de artículos del carrito
            //una vez hemos añadido el producto
            $this->update_precio_cantidad();
        }
        //método que actualiza el precio total y la cantidad
        //de productos total del carrito
        private function update_precio_cantidad()
        {
            //seteamos las variables precio y artículos a 0
            $precio = 0;
            $articulos = 0;
            //recorrecmos el contenido del carrito para actualizar
            //el precio total y el número de artículos
            foreach ($this->carrito as $row)
            {
                $precio += ($row['precio'] * $row['cantidad']);
                $articulos += $row['cantidad'];
            }
            //asignamos a articulos_total el número de artículos actual
            //y al precio el precio actual
            $_SESSION['carrito']["articulos_total"] = $articulos;
            $_SESSION['carrito']["precio_total"] = $precio;
            //refrescamos él contenido del carrito para que quedé actualizado
            $this->update_carrito();
        }
        //método que retorna el precio total del carrito
        public function precio_total()
        {
            //si no está definido el elemento precio_total o no existe el carrito
            //el precio total será 0
            if(!isset($this->carrito["precio_total"]) || $this->carrito === null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            //si no es númerico lanzamos una excepción porque no es correcto
            if(!is_numeric($this->carrito["precio_total"]))
            {
                throw new Exception("El precio total del carrito debe ser un número", 1);
            }
            //en otro caso devolvemos el precio total del carrito
            return $this->carrito["precio_total"] ? $this->carrito["precio_total"] : 0;
        }
            public function actualizar($precion,$idp)
        {
          
                   
            //creamos la id única para el producto
       $unique_id = md5($idp);
            //creamos la id única para el producto
            $articulo["unique_id"] = $unique_id;
           
        if(!empty($this->carrito))
            {
                foreach ($this->carrito as $row)
     
                {
                   
                     if($row["unique_id"] === $unique_id)
                    {
                        //si ya estaba sumamos la cantidad
                        $row["precio"] =$precion;
                    }
                   
                }
            }
              
        }
        //método que retorna el número de artículos del carrito
        public function articulos_total()
        {
            //si no está definido el elemento articulos_total o no existe el carrito
            //el número de artículos será de 0
            if(!isset($this->carrito["articulos_total"]) || $this->carrito === null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            //si no es númerico lanzamos una excepción porque no es correcto
            if(!is_numeric($this->carrito["articulos_total"]))
            {
                throw new Exception("El número de artículos del carrito debe ser un número", 1);
            }
            //en otro caso devolvemos el número de artículos del carrito
            return $this->carrito["articulos_total"] ? $this->carrito["articulos_total"] : 0;
        }
        //este método retorna el contenido del carrito
        public function get_content()
        {
            //asignamos el carrito a una variable
            $carrito = $this->carrito;
            //debemos eliminar del carrito el número de artículos
            //y el precio total para poder mostrar bien los artículos
            //ya que estos datos los devuelven los métodos 
            //articulos_total y precio_total
            unset($carrito["articulos_total"]);
            unset($carrito["precio_total"]);
            return $carrito;
        }
        //método que llamamos al insertar un nuevo producto al 
        //carrito para eliminarlo si existia, así podemos insertarlo
        //de nuevo pero actualizado
        private function unset_producto($unique_id)
        {
            unset($_SESSION["carritoa"][$unique_id]);
        }
        //para eliminar un producto debemos pasar la clave única
        //que contiene cada uno de ellos
        public function remove_producto($unique_id)
        {
            //si no existe el carrito
            if($this->carrito === null)
            {
                throw new Exception("El carrito no existe!", 1);
            }
            //si no existe la id única del producto en el carrito
            if(!isset($this->carrito[$unique_id]))
            {
                throw new Exception("La unique_id $unique_id no existe!", 1);
            }
            //en otro caso, eliminamos el producto, actualizamos el carrito y 
            //el precio y cantidad totales del carrito
            unset($_SESSION["carritoa"][$unique_id]);
            $this->update_carrito();
            $this->update_precio_cantidad();
            return true;
        }
        //eliminamos el contenido del carrito por completo
        public function destroy()
        {
            unset($_SESSION["carritoa"]);
            $this->carrito = null;
            return true;
        }
        //actualizamos el contenido del carrito
        public function update_carrito()
        {
            self::__construct();
        }
      public function agregaCliente($idc){
        if(!isset($_SESSION["carritoa"]))
            {
                 

                $_SESSION["cliente"] = $idc;
              

       }
      
    }
    }

    $carrito = new Carritoa();
    if ($_POST['accion']=='vaciar'){
        unset($_SESSION['idc']);
        $carrito->destroy();
    }
    if ($_POST['accion']=='act'){
    $pn=$_POST['precio'];
    $idp=$_POST['id'];

        $carrito->actualizar($pn,$idp);
    }
    if ($_POST['accion']=='asociar'){
        if (isset($_POST["idc"])){
            $id=$_POST["idc"];

                $_SESSION["idc"] = $id;}

    }
    if ($_POST['accion']=='listar'){
        $c=$carrito->get_content();
        echo json_encode($c);
       
    }else if ($_POST['accion']=='agregar'){
     $id=$_POST["id"];
        $P1=new Producto();
        $arrayprod=$P1->listarxID($id);
        $nombre=$arrayprod[0]["nombre"]; 
        $precio=$arrayprod[0]["precio"];
        $alicuota=$arrayprod[0]["aliiva"];   
        $marca=$arrayprod[0]["marca"];
     
        $articulo = array(
        "id"=>$_POST["id"],
        "cantidad"=>$_POST["cant"],
        "nombre"=>$nombre."  " .$marca,
        "precio"=>$precio,
        "alicuota"=>$alicuota
        
        ); 
       
        $carrito->add($articulo);
    }else if ($_POST["accion"]=='eliminar'){
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $carrito->remove_producto(md5($id));
    }else if ($_POST["accion"]=='obtener'){
        if (isset($_SESSION["idc"])){
      $idc=$_SESSION["idc"];
      }else{
         $idc=1;   
        }
      $cliente1=new Cliente();
      $c1=$cliente1->Obtener($idc);
     
      echo json_encode($c1);
        }


    ?>```
````

Comment: Cada que modifiques algo, no basta con actualizar `$this->carrito`, necesitas también actualizar las variables de sesión, por ejemplo: `$_SESSION['carritoa'] = $this->carrito;`

Comment: Ah entiendo..Pero como actualizo solo ese precio?O debo quitar todo el registro de ese producto y volverlo a cargar?

Comment: Recorres el arreglo buscando por ID de producto y actualiza si lo encuentras.

Comment: Es que eso hago dentro de la funcion, busco el id, dentro de un foreach